# Gitlab CI with Docker Images

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using a Gitlag Server and got 2 gitlab-runners (one on my local and one on a VServer) - both work perfectly with echo and simple stuff like building a ubuntu server with mysql and php

```
stages:
- dbserver
- deploy

build:
 stage: dbserver
 image: ubuntu:16.04  
   services:
   - mysql:5.7
 - php:7.0
variables:
   MYSQL_DATABASE: test
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test2
 script: 
   - apt-get update -q && apt-get install -qqy --no-install-recommends 
  mysql-client
   - mysql --user=root --password=\"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD\" --
     host=mysql < test.sql
```

I want to import a DB now, but I do not get the idea or the technic behind it. How do I import a .sql file lying on my local PC or server? Do I need to create a DOCKERFILE by myself or can I do that just with the gitlab.yml file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **scp** to copy the .sql file to the runner.

You may need to add the commands to install openssh-client e.g.:

```
script:
   apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y
```

and then just add the scp line before invoking mysql, e.g.:

```
- scp user@server:/path/to/file.sql /tmp/temp.sql
- mysql --user=root --password=\"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD\" --host=mysql < /tmp/temp.sql
```

Comment: So I need the .sql File on the Gitlab Server? I thought I just push it on the machine where the runner is installed and copy it from there.

Comment: From your question it wasn't clear where the original file.sql is. Of course, it can be anywhere, as long as you can ssh into that machine from your runner. That user@server I wrote was just an example

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which binds a directory from the gitlab-runner machine to the actual container I am using:

```
sudo nano /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml
```

there you change the volumes to something like this

```
volumes = ["/home/ubuntu/test:/cache"]
```

**/home/ubuntu/test** is the directory from the machine and **/cache** the one from the container

Before you do so I recommend to stop the runner and then start it again